# Railsサービス(mysql)をGKEにデプロイする際に秘密鍵が見つからずpodのstatusがCrashLoopBackOffになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

こちらteratailでも質問している内容（マルチポスト）です。
https://teratail.com/questions/198296

#### 前提・実現したいこと

自作railsアプリケーション（DBはMysql）をDocker環境で動くように開発し、GKE(google kubernetes engine)にデプロイしたい

[こちらのサイト](https://qiita.com/ryu-yama/items/dc640c35a56e42ebdba8)を参考にしています

前提
・アプリケーションはローカル（開発環境）だとdocker-compose upで正常に起動する状態
・localのワーキングディレクトリにはkey.jsonがある
・GCPのIAMと管理「サービス アカウントの詳細」にキーは設定されていてkey.jsonのものと同じ（メールアドレスも一致）
・cloudsql-db-credentialsとcloudsql-instance-credentialsはGCP側に設定されている

GKE構成
・nodeは2つ、それぞれに同じ2つpodを入れている
・マニュフェストファイルはひとつ(deployment.yml)

```js
#key.json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "プロジェクト名",
  "private_key_id": "・・・8a8c5",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n・・・BfYN\nMkTAtnTgtiC77mllNDhONA==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "test-user@プロジェクト名.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "・・・06700",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test-user%40プロジェクト名.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

GKEにデプロイする際にエラー（podのstatusがCrashLoopBackOff）になってしまう。

```rb
textPayload:  "/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:585:in `validate_secret_key_base': Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit` (ArgumentError)
```

```rb
textPayload:  "2019/07/02 14:18:29 invalid json file "./key.json": open ./key.json: no such file or directory
```

```sh
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
rails-api-798fd446db-c6jwc   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   1          5s
rails-api-798fd446db-d8g8k   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   1          5s
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```rb
#deployment.yml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rails-api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rails-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/プロジェクト名/rails_api
          name: web
          env:
            - name: DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                  key: username
            - name: DB_PASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                  key: password
            - name: DB_NAME
              value: SQLのインスタンス
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: 127.0.0.1
            - name: RAILS_ENV
              value: production
            - name: RACK_ENV
              value: production
            - name: RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES
              value: 'true'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: rails-api
          command: ["rm", "-f", "/rails_api/tmp/pids/server.pid"]
          command: ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-p", "3000", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
        - image: b.gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
          name: cloudsql-proxy
          command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                    "-instances=プロジェクト名:asia-northeast1:SQLのインスタンス=tcp:3306",
                    "-credential_file=./key.json"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
              mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
```

```rb
#Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.6.2


# 必要なパッケージのインストール（基本的に必要になってくるものだと思うので削らないこと）
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential \
                       libpq-dev \
                       nodejs

# 作業ディレクトリの作成、設定
RUN mkdir /rails_api
##作業ディレクトリ名をAPP_ROOTに割り当てて、以下$APP_ROOTで参照
ENV APP_ROOT /rails_api
WORKDIR $APP_ROOT

# ホスト側（ローカル）のGemfileを追加する（ローカルのGemfileは【３】で作成）
ADD ./Gemfile $APP_ROOT/Gemfile
ADD ./Gemfile.lock $APP_ROOT/Gemfile.lock

# Gemfileのbundle install
RUN bundle install
ADD . $APP_ROOT
```

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/198296

Comment: 申し訳ございません。stackoverflow初心者なものでマルチポストの問題意識がありませんでした。調べてみたところ質問にその旨を書いておく必要があると感じたので追記させていただきます。ご指摘ありがとうございました